# Where do I have to put @DeclareRoles?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

I basically understand the functions of `@DeclareRoles` and `@RolesAllowed`, but I'm not sure where to add the `@DeclareRoles` correctly. I testet with a  vaadin application with ejb session beans and cdi in glassfish 4. The application is packed as war not as ear.

- `@DeclareRoles` on **no** class: 
  Obviously nothing works. `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()` and `SessionContext.isCallerInRole()` are always returning false. `@RolesAllowed` always denies access.
- `@DeclareRoles` on the Servlet: 
  `@RolesAllowed` and `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()` are working as expected. `SessionContext.isCallerInRole()` is always returning false.
- `@DeclareRoles` on a session bean: 
  `@RolesAllowed`, `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()` and `SessionContext.isCallerInRole()` are working as expected. Even if `SessionContext.isCallerInRole()` is called in a different session bean than the one with `@DeclareRoles`

My question now are:

1. Where is the right place to put `@DeclareRoles`?
2. Is it ok to set it only once or should it annotate every bean that uses `SessionContext.isCallerInRole()` or `@RolesAllowed`?

Answer (score 4):

Method permissions can be specified on the class, the business methods of the class, or both. Method permissions can be specified on a method of the bean class to override the method permissions value specified on the entire bean class. The following annotations are used to specify method permissions:

- **@DeclareRoles:** Specifies all the roles that the application will use, including roles not specifically named in a **@RolesAllowed** annotation. The set of security roles the application uses is the total of the security roles defined in the @DeclareRoles and **@RolesAllowed** annotations.

The **@DeclareRoles** annotation is specified on a bean class, where it serves to declare roles that can be tested (for example, by calling isCallerInRole) from within the methods of the annotated class. When declaring the name of a role used as a parameter to the `isCallerInRole(String roleName)` method, the declared name must be the same as the parameter value.

The following example code demonstrates the use of the @DeclareRoles annotation:

```
@DeclareRoles("BusinessAdmin")
public class Calculator {
    ...
}
```

The syntax for declaring more than one role is as shown in the following example:

```
@DeclareRoles({"Administrator", "Manager", "Employee"})
```

- @RolesAllowed("list-of-roles"): Specifies the security roles permitted to access methods in an application. This annotation can be specified on a class or on one or more methods. When specified at the class level, the annotation applies to all methods in the class. When specified on a method, the annotation applies to that method only and overrides any values specified at the class level.

To specify that no roles are authorized to access methods in an application, use the @DenyAll annotation. To specify that a user in any role is authorized to access the application, use the @PermitAll annotation.

When used in conjunction with the @DeclareRoles annotation, the combined set of security roles is used by the application.

The following example code demonstrates the use of the **@RolesAllowed** annotation:

```
@DeclareRoles({"Administrator", "Manager", "Employee"})
public class Calculator {

    @RolesAllowed("Administrator")
    public void setNewRate(int rate) {
        ...
    }
}
```

- **@PermitAll**: Specifies that all security roles are permitted to execute the specified method or methods. The user is not checked against a database to ensure that he or she is authorized to access this application.

This annotation can be specified on a class or on one or more methods. Specifying this annotation on the class means that it applies to all methods of the class. Specifying it at the method level means that it applies to only that method.

The following example code demonstrates the use of the @PermitAll annotation:

```
import javax.annotation.security.*;
@RolesAllowed("RestrictedUsers")
public class Calculator {

    @RolesAllowed("Administrator")
    public void setNewRate(int rate) {
        //...
    }
    @PermitAll
    public long convertCurrency(long amount) {
        //...
    }
}
```

- **@DenyAll**: Specifies that no security roles are permitted to execute the specified method or methods. This means that these methods are excluded from execution in the Java EE container.

The following example code demonstrates the use of the @DenyAll annotation:

```
import javax.annotation.security.*;
@RolesAllowed("Users")
public class Calculator {
    @RolesAllowed("Administrator")
    public void setNewRate(int rate) {
        //...
    }
    @DenyAll
    public long convertCurrency(long amount) {
        //...
    }
}
```

The following code snippet demonstrates the use of the **@DeclareRoles** annotation with the *isCallerInRole* method. In this example, the **@DeclareRoles** annotation declares a role that the enterprise bean PayrollBean uses to make the security check by using `isCallerInRole("payroll")` to verify that the caller is authorized to change salary data:

```
@DeclareRoles("payroll")
@Stateless 
public class PayrollBean implements Payroll {

    @Resource SessionContext ctx;

    public void updateEmployeeInfo(EmplInfo info) {

        oldInfo = ... read from database;

        // The salary field can be changed only by callers
        // who have the security role "payroll"
        Principal callerPrincipal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
        if (info.salary != oldInfo.salary && !ctx.isCallerInRole("payroll")) {
            throw new SecurityException(...);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The following example code illustrates the use of the **@RolesAllowed** annotation:

```
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public class SomeClass {
    public void aMethod () {...}
    public void bMethod () {...}
    ...
}

@Stateless 
public class MyBean extends SomeClass implements A  {

    @RolesAllowed("HR")
    public void aMethod () {...}

    public void cMethod () {...}
    ...
}
```

More information:

[Securing Enterprise Beans](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/security-javaee002.html)